# Why does squeeze not work on sparse arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

x = np.eye(3)
print(x.sum(axis=1).shape)

x = sparse.eye(3)
print(x.sum(axis=1).shape)
print(x.sum(axis=1).squeeze().shape)
```

I got the following output:

```
(3,)
(3, 1)
(1, 3)
```

It looks like `squeeze` is not working as intended. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't used scipy.sparse but I'm pretty sure it handles _matrices_ rather than arrays, which are fixed 2d objects. Try with a numpy matrix rather than an array for comparison.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I need to use sparse matrices for my problem as they are too large. The code here was just a minimal example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [1]: from scipy import sparse                                                                 
In [2]: x = np.eye(3)                                                                            
In [3]: x                                                                                        
Out[3]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
In [4]: x.shape                                                                                  
Out[4]: (3, 3)

In [5]: xs = sparse.eye(3)                                                                       
In [6]: xs                                                                                       
Out[6]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
In [7]: print(xs)                                                                                
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
In [8]: xs.shape                                                                                 
Out[8]: (3, 3)
```

The `np` sum produces an array, with one less dimension (unless you use `keepdims` parameter)

```
In [9]: x.sum(axis=1)                                                                            
Out[9]: array([1., 1., 1.])
```

sparse sum produces a `np.matrix` object.

```
In [10]: xs.sum(axis=1)                                                                          
Out[10]: 
matrix([[1.],
        [1.],
        [1.]])
In [11]: _.shape                                                                                 
Out[11]: (3, 1)
```

`np.matrix` is, by definition, always 2d.  But it does have an `A1` property which converts to `ndarray` and applies squeeze.

```
In [12]: xs.sum(axis=1).A1                                                                       
Out[12]: array([1., 1., 1.])
```

---

Sparse actually performs the row or column sum by matrix multiplication:

```
In [21]: xs*np.matrix(np.ones((3,1)))                                                            
Out[21]: 
matrix([[1.],
        [1.],
        [1.]])
```

sparse matrix * np.matrix produces np.matrix

If `sum` used `ndarray`, the result would be an `ndarray`, and squeezeable

```
In [22]: xs*np.ones((3,1))                                                                       
Out[22]: 
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])
```

Note that I used `*` (I could have used @); the sparse definition of multiply (e.g. dot) has priority.

```
In [23]: np.matrix(np.ones((1,3)))*xs                                                            
Out[23]: matrix([[1., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: I didn't know about `A1`, thank you! So, squeeze doesn't work because np.matrix is always 2D?

Comment: Here `squeeze` is applied to a `np.matrix`, not to the sparse matrix.  But sparse matrices are also, by definition 2d.  `np.matrix` is a subclass of `ndarray`; sparse matrix is a separate class(s), but written to behave a lot like `np.matrix`.  `np.matrix` is on its way out, but switching sparse matrix to `ndarray` like behavior is a long way off.

Comment: Sparse sum is actually performed with matrix multiplication - see my edits.